# Any Bazel document to help migrate from an older version to newer version?

Tags: bazel

I am using Bazel 19 and I want to migrate to latest version 26. Looks like lot of things have changed and it is hard to figure out all changes from the release notes. Is there any document/tools that can help with migrating from older version to newer version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bazelisk](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk) provides a `--strict` and `--migrate` flag that can help you:

```
USE_BAZEL_VERSION=0.26.1 bazelisk --strict build //...
```

`--strict` enables all incompatible flags and helps you to identify upgrade problems.

If `--strict` fails you should try `--migrate`. It sets enables incompatible flags step by step and gives you a report of the incompatible flags that lead to a build problem:

```
USE_BAZEL_VERSION=0.26.1 bazelisk --migrate build //...
```

Take also a look at the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.25.0/backward-compatibility.html) about Backward Compatibility:

> When we introduce an incompatible change, we try to make it easier for
>   Bazel users to update their code. We do this by means of migration
>   windows and migration recipes.
>
> Migration window is one or more release of Bazel during which a
>   migration from old functionality to new functionality is possible,
>   according to a migration recipe.
>
> During the migration window, both the old functionality and the new
>   functionality are available in the Bazel release. For every
>   incompatible change, we provide a migration recipe that allows
>   updating the user code (BUILD and .bzl files, as well as any Bazel
>   usage in scripts, usage of Bazel API and so on) in such a way that it
>   works simultaneously without any flags with old and new functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach, in my opinion, is to incrementally update from 19 to 20, 20 to 21, and so on.

If you use [bazelisk](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk), version switching is easy:

1. `USE_BAZEL_VERSION=0.19.0 bazelisk test //...`
2. Fix breakages
3. Increment version and test: `USE_BAZEL_VERSION=0.20.0 bazelisk test //...`
4. Go back to 2.